# fetch first 2 words along with symbols

Tags: php, explode, implode

I am trying to fetch the first 2 words from a sting, the first word `Animal` and second word is `(Cat)` my current code does fetch it but the `()` brackets gets ignore I want to fetch exactly like on string `Animal (Cat)`.

```
echo implode(' ', array_slice(str_word_count($_POST['str'], 2), 0, 5));
```

Comment: Can you please let us know the input `$_POST['str']` and expected output as well, please?

Comment: say for example $str = 'Animal (Cat) is a domestic pet';

Comment: output i want is Animal (Cat)

Comment: Oh thanks! I guess you can use the `implode()` and `array_slice()` as well.

Comment: how can i achieve it please. thanks

Comment: Kindly check the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_slice` to get the first two words and then use `implode` to join them:

```
<?php
  $str = "Animal (Cat) is a domestic pet";
  echo implode(" ", array_slice(explode(" ", $str), 0, 2));
```

I get the output as:

```
Animal (Cat)
```

Here's a sandbox: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/a2c44

Comment: thanks it worked :)

Comment: and if supposing say i want every words before the (Cat) for example 'Why is Animal (Cat) a friendly pet' and get the output as 'Why is Animal (Cat)'

Comment: Yes il definitely accept it.

Comment: @Abigail Thanks and have a nice day. 

Comment: @Abigail Lemme try... You can try finding the position of the `(Cat)` and do something. Give me just one min.

Comment: can you help with that too please?

Comment: it may not always be (Cat) but the words before the () is what i want

Comment: @Abigail Check this out - **Input:** `A Cute Animal (Cat) is a domestic pet` and **Output:** `A Cute Animal (Cat)`. Does [**this code**](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/31d7e) help?

Comment: Yes yes exactly it could be A Cute Animal (Cat) or A Cute Animal (Dog) or any other animal name

Comment: @Abigail Lemme try, I know how to do that in JavaScript. But in PHP, I don't think that's possible. It's really seems tough, and can you ask another question, this seems a nice one.

Comment: Sure not an issue really appreciate your help. greatful :)

Comment: Will have to wait 90 minutes :(

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow another question now

Comment: @Abigail Give me a moment.

Comment: lol good one :) i did it

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier.  Just tokenize on a space twice:

```
echo strtok($_POST['str'], ' ') . ' ' . strtok(' ');
```